# PreferenceActivity creates threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, preferences

I launched my application in debug mode (IDE: Eclipse 4.4) and noticed, that when I open Settings Activity (which extends PreferenceActivity) a new thread with name "PowerManagerThread" appears. Also, when I click on any CheckBoxPreference another thread appears: "pool-2-thread-1". These threads remains even after Settings Activity is destroyed. What are these threads doing and are they neccessary?

Edit.
I created a new project with MainActivity, containing a PreferenceFragment with single checkbox. Then i changed that to PreferenceActivity(as described above). Same threads appeared in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thread "pool-2-thread-1" is created by an executor service, which you used in your code (could be also created by any of your used library) and need to shutdown.